# Updating multiple tables using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, strongly-typed-dataset, multiple-tables

I've been trawling through pages and pages on the internet for days now trying different approaches and I'm still not sure how I should be doing this.

On my third InsertCommand, I'd like to reference a column on the other 2 tables.

```
// Populate a DataSet from multiple Tables... Works fine
sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
sqlDA.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM hardware", sqlConn);
sqlDA.Fill(ds, "Hardware");
sqlDA.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM software";
sqlDA.Fill(ds, "Software");
sqlDA.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM join_hardware_software";
sqlDA.Fill(ds, "HS Join");

// After DataSet has been changed, perform an Insert on relevant tables...
updatedDs = ds.GetChanges();
SqlCommand DAInsertCommand = new SqlCommand();
DAInsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO hardware (host, model, serial) VALUES (@host, @model, @serial)";
DAInsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@host", null).SourceColumn = "host";
DAInsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", null).SourceColumn = "model";
DAInsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serial", null).SourceColumn = "serial";
sqlDA.InsertCommand = DAInsertCommand;
sqlDA.Update(updatedDs, "Hardware"); // Works Fine

DAInsertCommand.Parameters.Clear(); // Clear parameters set above
DAInsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO software (description) VALUES (@software)";
DAInsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@software", null).SourceColumn = "description";
sqlDA.InsertCommand = DAInsertCommand;
sqlDA.Update(updatedDs, "Software"); // Works Fine

DAInsertCommand.Parameters.Clear(); // Clear parameters set above
DAInsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO join_hardware_software (hardware_id, software_id) VALUES (@hardware_id, @software_id)";
// *****
DAInsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hardware_id", null).SourceColumn = "?"; // I want to set this to be set to my 'hardware' table to the 'id' column.
DAInsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@software_id", null).SourceColumn = "?"; // I want to set this to be set to my 'software' table to the 'id' column.
// *****
sqlDA.InsertCommand = DAInsertCommand;
sqlDA.Update(updatedDs, "HS Join");
```

Could somebody please tell me where I am going wrong and how I could potentially overcome this? Many thanks! :)

Comment: If your inserts into Hardware and Software returned the ids then you could use them. Maybe this link might help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Surely you need some values in the insert into your 'join' table. I guess that's what you're trying to do with SourceColumn but I'm not certain if you can use it that way.

Comment: Sorry, updatedDs = ds.getChanges()... Yes Daniel, I need to somehow retrieve the IDs of the colums in the first 2 tables. I just read that article, haven't used Parameter Directions before but I'll read into it. I'm pretty sure I'm doing all of this completely wrong but I just don't know how the average .NET Developer would read data from multiple SQL tables into a DataSet, modify the DataSet using a DataGridView and then post the DataSet back to the relevant SQL tables. Thanks for your inputs! :)

Comment: Try adding an output parameter to each of the first two inserts. Then you can use their returned values in the final insert. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: I'm really lost in all of this... I did what you said and added this just above the sqlDA.Update(updatedDs, "Hardware"); ...............                     SqlParameter testOutParam = new SqlParameter("@hardware_id", SqlDbType.Int);
                    testOutParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    testOutParam.SourceColumn = "id";
                    DAInsertCommand.Parameters.Add(testOutParam); I tried a MessageBox.Show(testOutParam.Value.ToString()); which returned null.

Comment: If you add an Output Parameter to each of the first two inserts then read their values, you'll be able to use them in the last insert. I think you'll need to add the Output Parameter first. Let me know how it goes. I think you've got caught up with using Source Column. When I've used Parameters.AddWithValue I've not used SourceColumn. If I get chance I'll try and replicate your code on my machine and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I dumped the latest here http://pastebin.com/P1qkYLMV. The problem is now is that in order to perform each sqlDA.Update I need to clear the previous Parameters otherwise the next Insert will be expecting them and throws an error.

Comment: It seems I'm not getting anywhere with SqlDataAdaptor. The reason I wanted to use it is because I wanted users to be able to have the flexability with using a DataGridView to view and change data. I thought this is why DataSets were supposed to be useful and everything was working great until the spec changed and I needed to link hardware id's to software id's... If there is an easier way I'd love to know! Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to your comments this seems to be one of those occasions where if you and I were sat next to each other we'd get this sorted but it's a bit tricky.

This is code I've used when working with SqlConnection and SqlCommand. There might be stuff here that would help you.

```
    public static void RunSqlCommandText(string connectionString, string commandText) {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();

        try {
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comm.CommandText = commandText;

            comm.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog el = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            el.Source = "data access class";
            el.WriteEntry(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + " SQL '" + commandText + "'");
        } finally {
            conn.Close();
            comm.Dispose();
        }
    }


    public static int RunSqlAndReturnId(string connectionString, string commandText) {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
        int id = -1;

        try {
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comm.CommandText = commandText;

            comm.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            var returnvalue = comm.ExecuteScalar();
            if (returnvalue != null) {
                id = (int)returnvalue;                
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog el = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            el.Source = "data access class";
            el.WriteEntry(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + " SQL '" + commandText + "'");
        } finally {
            conn.Close();
            comm.Dispose();
        }

        return id;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this kind of approach may be the way I have to go which is a shame because I would have prefered to work with a DataSet since my app will be heavily dependant on a relational SQL backend and I feel that DataSets are the best thing for that. The app is going to eventually be a kind of asset tracking program heavily tailored for my department. Thank you for your help Daniel, you've been most patient! :)

Comment: Don't give up on the other method. Once you've got it working this way then it might give you clues to get the other method working.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/549226/1648429. It seems a bit over the top having to specify my foreign keys explicitly, but heck I'll give anything a go...

Comment: Maybe it's not that over the top. I've always thought of DataSets as being snapshots of a database so if you're using it to transfer info from a web form to an actual database then you'll probably want the DataSet to know this information so it can enact constraints and so on.

Comment: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/10/31/returnidentityvaluequery.aspx
] describes one way to achieve this, although it's using strongly-typed datasets