# Bulk Insert DataSet with multiple related tables into SQL Server C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, foreign-keys, dataset

I have a DataSet with multiple tables the source document is an XML file.

`mydataset.ReadXML(filename);`

There are multiple tables with multiple relations. I have the database in the SQL created via code - tables, columns and relations.

Now I would like to insert the data . (Yes I want everything).
**EDIT:** The SQL tables use Identity Columns autogenerate - because I am not sure the incoming data will never duplicate one of the parameters that I would like to assume is unique.

So what methods should I do to ensure data is input considering I have foreign key constraints , how should I iterate the the tables in the dataset to make sure I don't try to insert in tables requiring an existing id. Do I create a hard coded map (I prefer not too)  , or do I walk the tables looking for a Foreign key and verify the parent table etc..

Any Ideas ? I am sure someone has done this before and has a simple answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.  Assuming the database is not generating the key values, this is pretty simple.  Either

1) You discover the order to load the tables so that each table with a Foreign Key is loaded *after* the table to which it refers.

2) You turn off constraint checking in [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), and then optionally check the constraints after loading.

To check the constraints after load, run a command like

```
alter table SomeTable with check check constraint fk_SomeTable_OtherTable
```

If you do have database-generated keys, this is all harder.  But the best way to tackle that is to use SEQUENCE objects isntead of IDENTITY columns and run [sp_sequence_get_range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-sequence-get-range-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to fetch the new key ranges to the client and apply the keys there first.

Comment: The SQL server is generating the new Identity columns - as I don't know if the incoming jobs data will ever have duplicate info in the xml files that can't be guaranteed and I do not want to kill the process because of a duplicated info that might be a year old or even a week old.

Comment: I am thinking of maybe trying to use the dataset.CreateReader() on the tables and then try to update the database somehow - but I need to study that - maybe even translate<TEntity> to try it - just need to do some research first I looking for simple and also re-usability ..Any thoughts about those ?

Comment: I don’t see how that helps. SqlBulkCopy and SqlDataAdapter both already know how to update the database.